# Is it possible to have multiple STDIN streams?

Tags: ruby, stream, usb, stdin, barcode

I'm hoping to connect two USB barcode scanners to a single computer, allowing two people to scan ticket barcodes simultaneously.  If both people scan at the same time, however, the input from STDIN will get messy.

Is there a way to set up different STDIN streams, each tied to a specific USB port?  The console script is in Ruby, though pointers in any language would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's limiting you to only using STDIN as your input?

Comment: What are my other options?  Isn't that where I'd have to listen to get the USB data streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try connecting 2 USB barcode scanners first and test if what you are afraid of happens. I suspect all barcode digits are sent in a single burst while interrupts from other keyboard-like devices are on hold - so you won't get two barcodes "interlaced" together.

It's impossible to have more than one stdin, not literally. Other options will depend based on the OS you are on - on linux maybe the drivers provide you different character devices for different scanners. On Windows i believe you will have to learn talking the USB HID protocol... best if you don't have to do any of that.

Comment: That was exactly what happened.  As far as I could test there was no 'interlacing'.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question directly, there is no way to have more than one STDIN.  You're best bet would be to read the data from a file (I would think you should have a character device or something for this scanner)

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a Mutex to synchronize them so only one scan can be processed at a time?

Here's a tutorial on working with threads in Ruby

http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_threads.html

Comment: This seems absurd to me, prey tell - how do you think you can use mutex on barcode scanners that are connected as USB HID? To make imagery simple, let's connect 2 keyboards through USB - they both simultaneously pour in STDIN. How will you distinguish them?!